How can the reverse of a rule which contains two arguments be defined in Mathematica?
Suppose I have a rule in Mathematica:
x -> x[a] defined under some variable. Is there a way I can use the reverse of the rule x[a] -> x in my code?
As an example, consider this code for finding the Hamiltonian from the Lagrangian:
coordrep = {t -> t[τ], r -> r[τ], x -> x[τ], θ -> θ[τ], 
            t' -> t'[τ], r' -> r'[τ], x' -> x'[τ], θ' -> θ'[τ]};

u0 = Log[2/5];

lagrangian = E^(2 u0 + 2 a x^2)/(
     2/5) (-(t')^2 + T[x] (θ')^2 + (r')^2 - r^2 α^2) + (
     2 a^2 x^2)/T[x] (x')^2 /. coordrep;

Pt = D[lagrangian, t'[τ]];

Px = D[lagrangian, x'[τ]];

Pr = D[lagrangian, r'[τ]];

Pθ = D[lagrangian, θ'[τ]];

hamiltonian = ((Pt t'[τ] + Px x'[τ] + Pr r'[τ] + Pθ θ'[τ]) - 
        lagrangian) /. (Solve[{pt[τ] == Pt, px[τ] == Px, 
          pr[τ] == Pr, 
          pθ[τ] == Pθ}, {t'[τ], x'[τ], 
          r'[τ], θ'[τ]}] // Last) /. 
     pt[τ] -> En /. pθ[τ] -> k // Expand;

Once I have found my Hamiltonian, is there a way by which I can go from something like r[τ] -> r using the original variable coordrep?
Edit
I tried the methods given in the comments for the following code below:
coordrep1 = {t -> t[\[Tau]], r -> r[\[Tau], \[Sigma]], 
   x -> x[\[Tau], \[Sigma]]};

coordrep2 = {t' -> t'[\[Tau]], r' -> r'[\[Tau], \[Sigma]], 
   x' -> x'[\[Tau], \[Sigma]]};
coordrep3 = {
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(t\), \(.\)]\) -> 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(t\), \(.\)]\)[\[Tau]], 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(r\), \(.\)]\) -> 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(r\), \(.\)]\)[\[Tau], \[Sigma]], 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(.\)]\) -> 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(.\)]\)[\[Tau], \[Sigma]]};

met1 = DiagonalMatrix[{gtt, g11, g22, g33, grr}] /. coordrep1;

X = {t, x, 0, 0, r} /. coordrep1;

dXdtau = D[X, \[Tau]];

dXdsigma = D[X, \[Sigma]];

gammaTT = 
  Sum[dXdtau[[\[Mu]]] met1[[\[Mu], \[Nu]]] dXdtau[[\[Nu]]], {\[Mu], 1,
     5}, {\[Nu], 1, 5}];

gammaSS = 
  Sum[dXdsigma[[\[Mu]]] met1[[\[Mu], \[Nu]]] dXdsigma[[\[Nu]]], \
{\[Mu], 1, 5}, {\[Nu], 1, 5}];

gammaTS = 
  Sum[dXdtau[[\[Mu]]] met1[[\[Mu], \[Nu]]] dXdsigma[[\[Nu]]], {\[Mu], 
    1, 5}, {\[Nu], 1, 5}];

gamma = {{gammaTT, gammaTS}, {gammaTS, gammaSS}};

Format[Derivative[n_, 0 ..][f_][\[Tau], vars___]] := 
 OverDot[f][\[Tau], vars]

Format[Derivative[0 .., n_][f_][vars___, \[Sigma]]] := 
 f'[vars, \[Sigma]]

detGamma = Det[gamma] // Simplify

finaldetGamma = 
 detGamma /. Reverse[coordrep2, 2] /. Reverse[coordrep3, 2]

Sadly, they don't seem to work. Is there a better way to handle rules when you have two arguments in the function?

What about Reverse[a -> b]?

Will Reverse[coordrep] work too?

It is a list of rules so Reverse/@coordrep will work.

So, hamiltonian /. Reverse /@ coordrep should work, right?

Not an answer but a workflow framework I use frequently: vars = Hold[t, r, x, \[Theta]]; Clear @@ vars; Clear[\[Tau]]; vars = List @@ vars; applyDep = (v : Alternatives @@ Join[vars, Derivative[__] /@ vars]) :> v[\[Tau]]; stripDep = (v : Alternatives @@ Join[vars, Derivative[__] /@ vars])[\[Tau]] :> v;. One can also do Through[vars[0]] = icVector and Through[Thread[vars'][0]] =... and other operations that depend on vars.

Also Reverse[coordrep, 2] (and (Operate[ReverseApplied, #] & /@ coordrep))

……As the function name of Format suggests, it's only for formatting and won't change the FullForm of the code. Remove the Format i.e. use Derivative[n_, 0 ..][f_][\[Tau], vars___] :=    OverDot[f][\[Tau], vars]; Derivative[0 .., n_][f_][vars___, \[Sigma]] :=    f'[vars, \[Sigma]], then the code should work as expected.

@xzczd Thank you for the much needed help :)
